# Why can't I update an anchor tag with JQuery?

Tags: jquery

Here is my code but it's not working as expected. Given an interval, I want to update an anchor tag but it never updates. How can I do this? I'm really very new to JQuery so an example or pointing me to to something that spells it out for me would be greatly appreciated.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"flag.asp",
    dataType:"text",
    type:'POST',
    success:function(flag){
      if(flag != 'true'){
        $("#test").attr({href:'somepath/somefile'});
        $.ajax({
          url:"context.asp",
          data:{var1:var1},
          type:'POST',
          success:function(flag){
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
},8000);
```

Comment: Why do you need AJAX for? Please clarify your question

Comment: Have you stepped through with your browser's debugger? Looks to me like the most probable answer is `flag` is equal to `'true'`

Comment: Please provide the HTML, too (maybe build a jsbin or jsfiddle for it). Thanks

Comment: ... or your AJAX requests results in an error. In any case, your browser has an developer console that can log errors and (probably) show requests (look in the *Net* tab). I suggest you start there

Comment: @Phil. Maybe I should add an error function to it and see if I get anything back>

Comment: @NaN : Does your anchor tag have an id `#test`? Also what do you get in browser console?

Comment: I get a 200 in the console. I can see it posting just fine. Also, my anchor tag does have the id test. I'm baffled. Is there something about an AJAX call that prevents this sort of action from happening?

Comment: Just for fun, I even tried to set a dropdown box and it won't set it while inside the success function of the ajax call. I've even tried setting the dropdown from the error function and I get nothing. If I remove the code from iside the ajax call, everything works fine

Comment: @NaN What is the response of the first AJAX POST request? The fact that you're only seeing one AJAX POST re-affirms my first assumption; your first request to `flag.asp` has a response of `true`

Comment: @Phil, why did you remove your answer?

Comment: @NaN It was incorrect. You've shown that `flag` is definitely not "true". Without seeing any HTML, I cannot assist further. Do you possibly have multiple elements with ID `test`? Again, I'd suggest setting a breakpoint at the `$('#test')...` line and debugging properly.

Comment: Ok. As long as I didn't make you upset. I honestly wasn't laughing, I was just certain that 'flag' wasn't true. Anyhow, if you could tell me how I could use the browser to troubleshoot this, I'd be grateful. I'm really new to JQ and I know that Firebug can help me. I've already checked and there are no other elements with that same id name.

Comment: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Script_Debugging. I use Chrome so it's a little different. You find your JS in the *Sources* tab and set breakpoints by clicking on the line number. When your script hits that point, it will pause. You can then press `ESC` to bring up the console and run any sort of command you like. I'd probably start with `$('#test')`. The results will display in the console.

Comment: Thanks Phil. I'm using Firefox but it should be the same I imagine. I've not done anything with breakpoints but I'll try it right now. I'll let you know in a few what I find

Comment: OK, Phil. I've set a breakpoint on the success function and honestly, I don't know what I'm looking at here. Can you translate it? What should I be looking at?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36701/discussion-between-phil-and-nan)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add into ajax Option > async = true

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"flag.asp",
    dataType:"text",
    type:'POST',
    async: true,
    success:function(flag){
      if(flag != 'true'){
        $.ajax({
          url:"context.asp",
          data:{var1:var1},
          type:'POST',
          success:function(flag){

               $("#test").attr({href:'somepath/somefile'});
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
},8000);
```

Comment: Cho, that didn't do anything. The href is never updated with the value I have.

Comment: Have you tried this ? >> $("#test").attr("href", "someValue");

Comment: I have. I've tried that inside the success block and that's where it will not work. If I remove it from outside the ajax call, it works as expected. Someone said something about using a callback but I'm not that familiar with JQuery and an not sure how to implement that to even try

Answer (score 0):

i dont know much about jquery  but i think href attribute cannot be updated like this

```
$("#test").attr({href:'somepath/somefile'});
```

but it should be

```
$("#test").attr('href','http://example.com');
```

see your updated  code as below

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"flag.asp",
    dataType:"text",
    type:'POST',
    success:function(flag){
      if(flag != 'true'){
        $("#test").attr('href','http://example.com');
        $.ajax({
          url:"context.asp",
          data:{var1:var1},
          type:'POST',
          success:function(flag){
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
},8000);
```

Comment: If I remove the `.attr` method from the success block it works fine. The issue I'm having is inside the success block

Comment: then i am sorry as i told i dont know much about jquery so i might be wrong .. sorry again

Comment: No problem. I really appreciate you lending a hand and looking at my code. Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks Phil. I just fixed the key/value issue but I'm still not getting the result.

Comment: @Nan There was nothing to fix, you were using `attr()` correctly